# Error In ICS VPN Android Github Library By Kghost

Tags: android, android-ndk, vpn, ics-openvpn

I'm implementing VPN Clinet App using this link
https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn
I've implemented all classes and ndk, jni folder. but i'am getting the following error. Can you tell me where i am wrong, I know little bit about NDK programming.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.1_10cd953c940accdea77ebb67004f63b8f836c70e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_97c69303320b681f6d7d87eadc7fa921f02ff155-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_8a18f2f1952aa425d384a1e33242b2e3b5e2451b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_67e7c6ea9a171280f91b75a018c8adc4f2583f0f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_5405f48ddd551053ab3c0faa550d0ec7f6f1ae3a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_48aecd695d9fdbb32686a2e497fcb23eaf97dcc2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-24.2.1_015eb2a0704b5b24bf9edd7a8aa027b09e4eb25e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-24.2.1_e542563c5b210b1167d539455a89614edf099333-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-media-compat-24.2.1_01e8fb230f45ea3f0fb2e67b1d54b1f51a216412-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-fragment-24.2.1_8cd128ce027a6fd9a390c47a9cc03e67f962b7ef-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-utils-24.2.1_68e7b0016482a99658f41239a4ac0693d7b6cc38-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-ui-24.2.1_0b4d927e6320c6127e3dd9e5e5befe04121bb575-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-compat-24.2.1_872731fbcd26ccbf333b71659f8077f805fb1ae2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-24.2.1_14596ea6531416e72d0f833c11191aff4ba9f7f8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.goyal.demovpn/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-24.2.1_9b888db785276461b4db8014854697864f2ecd31-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjni_openvpn.so"
                                                                      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
                                                                      at com.goteso.demovpn.openvpn.OpenVpnService.<clinit>(OpenVpnService.java:508)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1656)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3094)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
```

Comment: you might placed native libraries in wrong directory, and dex executable can't find them

Comment: which type of native libraries are you saying..

Comment: LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/main/aidl/com/goyal/demovpn/openvpn/IVpnService.aidl

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := OpenVpn
#LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libjni_openvpn

LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := libjni_openvpn

#LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

ifeq ($(strip $(LOCAL_PACKAGE_OVERRIDES)),)
# Use the following include to make our test apk.
include $(call all-makefiles-under, $(LOCAL_PATH))
endif

Comment: Above comment is android.mk file

Comment: Vlad Matvienko, Can you tell me where i am wrong..? I can send you the project also.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in NDK. I wrote what I saw. The error message means that can't find a file:    
`nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjni_openvpn.so"` Unfortunately I can't say anything else

Comment: what is the best learning platform for ndk app development.?

Comment: there is no `the best`. it is oppinion-based.

Comment: Do you have any exp. in android VPN implementation.?

Comment: I'm developing the VPN client app. but didn't to get anything from internet. Will you please help me in this matter..?

Comment: no, I don't have. You should ask a question about VPN implementation I think.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run build-native.sh from the misc folder first?

- If it can't find .git file, update your submodule as instructed.
- If it can't find ndk-build: add it to your environment variables.
- If the build errors, download ndk r12b. r13 and r14 seem to break the build.